# %d with Long Int

Tags: c, printf, long-integer, scanf

Is the following code Correct?As far as my understanding,it should not work properly,but on the Dev-C++ Compiler,it does.Could someone explain in detail please?

```
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{
long int num_case=LONG_MAX;

scanf("%d",&num_case);

printf("%ld",num_case);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should `scanf` for a `%ld` if that is what you are expecting. But since a `long` is larger than your typical `int`, there is no issue with this.

Comment: **Do not use the compiler that comes with Dev-C++** - it is extremely outdated! See http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most things that the standard C library tells you not to do, it invokes undefined behavior. Undefined means it might work under some conditions yet crash when you least expect it.

In this case, it works because `long int` and `int` are actually the same numeric representation: four byte, two's complement. With another platform (for example x86-64 Linux), that might not be the case, and you would probably see some sort of problem. In particular, the high-order bytes of the 8-byte `long int` would be left uninitialized.

**EDIT:** Asking "but will it crash" is *thinking the wrong way*. Merely reading uninitialized bytes into a variable of type `long int` is allowed to crash a C program, according to the language standard. We don't need to find an example of a platform which does so, to understand that the program is ill-specified. That is the point. C does not throw the rulebook at you right away, it waits until you port and break initial assumptions.

Comment: That is unless x86-64 is Windows where long int stays 32 bit.

Comment: Would there really be a problem? I mean, the number won't represent what we want but this won't cause the program to crash in any way, right? A concerning 64 bits, the only true integer type to be 64 bits is long long, which has been introduced in C99 and is part of the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Geoffroy Proceeding to run a program with uninitialized or unexpected values is likely to cause a crash, although I never mentioned a crash; I said "some sort of problem." Usually we want to avoid *all* misbehavior, not just crashes. On Mac OS and Linux, `long` and `long long` are both 64 bits; I was not aware that Windows did things otherwise, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

As RageD says, you really should use %ld in the `scanf()` call. The reason why it works is because on your system (or so it appears to me), `int` and `long int` are the same size (probably 4), so `scanf()` does not overwrite any memory it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on 32 bit systems long int have 32 bits (same as int) and on 64 bits system long int have 64 bits (same as long long int). If you want your code to be portable, use scanf with "%ld".